# How to use TcpStream with Arc

Tags: rust

I have a `TcpStream`, and i'm trying to create a dedicated thread to read from `TcpStream` and the main thread should do the write only, so i wrapped the `TcpStream` inside an Arc to share ownership.
Here is my code

```
fn main() {
    let mut tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    let tcp_stream = Arc::new(&mut tcp_stream);
}
fn read_from_stream(tcp_stream: Arc<&mut TcpStream>) {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    tcp_stream.read_to_string(&mut buffer);
}
```

I got the error **Cannot borrow data in Arc as mutable**. But the `tcp_stream` needs to be mutable in order to call `read_to_string` method.
What should i do to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `Arc` does inhibit mutability, in this case that's not an issue because `&TcpStream` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.TcpStream.html#impl-Read-for-%26TcpStream) `Read`.

Therefore you can wrap `TcpStream` (not `&mut TcpStream`) in `Arc` and call `read_to_string()` on the shared `&TcpStream` reference obtained with `Arc::as_ref()`:

```
fn main() {
    let tcp_stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
    let tcp_stream = Arc::new(tcp_stream);
}

fn read_from_stream(tcp_stream: Arc<TcpStream>) {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    tcp_stream.as_ref().read_to_string(&mut buffer);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7f7264f793c47a184a5763d365c3ef6)

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> Shared references in Rust disallow mutation by default, and `Arc` is no
> exception: you cannot generally obtain a mutable reference to
> something inside an `Arc`. If you need to mutate through an `Arc`, use
> `Mutex`, `RwLock`, or one of the Atomic types.

In your case, I would go either with `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

Example using `Mutex`:

```rust
fn main()
{
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("127.0.0.1:34254").unwrap();
    let stream = Arc::new(Mutex::new(stream));
    read_from_stream(stream);
}

fn read_from_stream(tcp_stream: Arc<Mutex<TcpStream>>)
{
    let mut buffer = String::new();

    let mut tcp_stream = tcp_stream.lock().unwrap();
    tcp_stream.read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
}
```